# Battery capacity evaluation

Tags: batteries, discharge, charge, capacity, measure

To measure NiMH battery capacity, everything I've read so far indicates that in order to get an accurate evaluation you have to measure the discharge parameters.
I can understand that, however in my mind it would be easier and more efficient to measure the batteries charging parameters. Then the battery can be immediately used and you'll know exactly what to expect without going through a discharge/charge cycle.
I really think this can be done - bear in mind I'm really not interested in a very accurate measure, a ballpark number would suffice.
Anyway, remember what goes in must come out, of course with some intrinsic loses.

Comment: Re, "in order to get an _accurate_ evaluation you have to...[BUT] bear in mind, I'm not interested in a very accurate measure." Well, there you go then!

Comment: You can't use coulomb counting accurately on charge if you start with a partially charged battery.